# Assembler Code, Calculating sum of squares without multiplication using only loops and addition. Infinite loop. ASCII/Hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, ascii, square

I have a project to create an assembler code to find the sum of numbers.

write an assembly language program to perform the following operation:Input a positive integer N, then compute the sum of the integers equal to N.
=1+4+9+⋯+
The user input will ALWAYS be a two-digit number (between 01 and 10). You do NOT need to check the correctness of the input. For example, if the user input is “10”, then your program will output “385”.

If User input is 03 output should be 14 i.e. 1+4+9

The Assembler used is based on Morris Mano book.
Here are all the codes that can be used. 
I have come up with a looping system to calculate the sum but it is infinite and crashes if i input any number greater than 1.
Also unsure how to convert output back to ASCII.

```
/read the first character
CIF1, SKI     /skip if input flag is set
BUN CIF1  /loop until input flag is set
INP       /read a character from the input reg
ADD NZR   /add -30 hex (subtract 30 hex)
STA ASD   /store value into MSD
CLA       /clear the accumulator

/SZA  /only if input is 0, otherwise it is 10

/read the second character
CIF2, SKI     
BUN CIF2
INP
ADD NZR
STA BSD /store second number in memory
CLA /clear accumulator

/loop for calculation 
BUN ACCU /call subroutine ACCU to find SUM/TOTAL

LOOP,LDA SQR  /load the odd value i.e. 1, 4, 9, 16...
 ADD TWO  /adds two
 ADD ODD  /adds the odd number
 STA SQR  /store the square

 LDA ODD /load the stored odd number
 ADD TWO /adds two current odd value
 STA ODD /stores the odd value i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7...
 /BUN ACCU /branch to subroutine to find SUM/ANSWER


 ACCU,LDA SQR //Accumulate the total SUM
 ADD SUM 
 STA SUM    
 LDA BSD /Load second input number
 ADD SUB /subtract 1 from input number until hits 0?
 SZA /skip out of loop
 BUN LOOP /loop to top

/output the sum
LDA SUM
ADD PZR
OUT
HLT /end program
/output third character?????

/declared variables
ODD, DEC 1 /first vale(1) and new storage for value when odd+2
TWO, DEC 2 /add 2 to the odd numbers: 1+2=3, 3+5=7 etc.
SQR, DEC 1 /first square(1) and stores the square i.e. 4, 9, 16, 25    
SUM, DEC 0/Starts at 1, The ANSWER or sum of numbers
SUB, DEC -1/ Subtract 1 from input #(until 0)u

ASD, DEC 0 /where first character is stored
BSD, DEC 0 /where second character is stored
CSD, DEC 0 /Third character output if needed
NZR, HEX -30 /converts to input
PZR, HEX 30 /converts to output
END
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Trying my best, already traced through the code multiple times and have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I will try to debug in my head, you should see the similar things in debugger, when single-stepping over instructions (The input will be "03"):

```
/read the first character
CIF1, SKI     /skip if input flag is set
BUN CIF1  /loop until input flag is set
INP       /read a character from the input reg
ADD NZR   /add -30 hex (subtract 30 hex)
STA ASD   /store value into MSD
   *** ASD = ACC = 0  - and it will be never touched again
   *** (will not work for "10" input)
CLA       /clear the accumulator

/read the second character
CIF2, SKI     
BUN CIF2
INP
ADD NZR
STA BSD /store second number in memory
   *** BSD = ACC = 3
CLA /clear accumulator

/loop for calculation 
BUN ACCU /call subroutine ACCU to find SUM/TOTAL
   *** goes to ACCU label (it's not call, for call there is BSA instruction)
   .... (jumping there) ...

 ACCU,LDA SQR //Accumulate the total SUM
      *** ACC = SQR (1)
 ADD SUM
      *** ACC += SUM (0) == 1
 STA SUM
      *** SUM = 1
 LDA BSD /Load second input number
      *** ACC = 3
 ADD SUB /subtract 1 from input number until hits 0?
      *** ACC = 2 (BSD is still 3)
 SZA /skip out of loop
 BUN LOOP /loop to top
      *** jumps to loop

LOOP,LDA SQR  /load the odd value i.e. 1, 4, 9, 16...
      *** ACC = SQR (1)
 ADD TWO  /adds two
      *** ACC = 3
 ADD ODD  /adds the odd number
      *** ACC = 4
 STA SQR  /store the square
      *** SQR = 4 (ok)
 LDA ODD /load the stored odd number
 ADD TWO /adds two current odd value
 STA ODD /stores the odd value i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7...
      *** ODD = 3 (you could have moved this ahead of SQR update)
      *** (to avoid one "ADD TWO")

 ACCU,LDA SQR //Accumulate the total SUM
      *** ACC = SQR (4)
 ADD SUM
      *** ACC = 5
 STA SUM
      *** SUM = 5
 LDA BSD /Load second input number
      *** ACC = 3
 ADD SUB /subtract 1 from input number until hits 0?
      *** ACC = 2
 SZA /skip out of loop
 BUN LOOP /loop to top
      *** jumps to loop again (BSD is still 3)
```

And I hope it's obvious why infinite loop happens.

And that's what you should have seen in debugger, that the second `LDA BSD` doesn't load ACC with expected 2, but 3.

Comment: @snipshow7 also check old question chat, I added some notes there, but I'm not sure how to notify you about that.